# When and Where is the Next World Classic Chess Championship?

Tags: tournament, world-championship, international-master

I am curious to know the details about the next World Classic Chess Championship. Specifically, I would like to find out when and where it will be held.

Answer (score 4):

The date and venue for the Chess World Championship(Classical) are still not out. It's usually decided after the Candidates tournament is over. Candidates will happen from 2-25 April 2024 in Toronto, Canada.